# Loop & output content_tags within content_tag in helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, helper, block

I'm trying a helper method that will output a list of items, to be called like so:

```
foo_list( ['item_one', link_to( 'item_two', '#' ) ... ] )
```

I have written the helper like so after reading [Using helpers in rails 3 to output html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561250/using-helpers-in-rails-3-to-output-html):

```
def foo_list items
    content_tag :ul do
        items.collect {|item| content_tag(:li, item)}
    end
end
```

However I just get an empty UL in that case, if I do this as a test:

```
def foo_list items
    content_tag :ul do
        content_tag(:li, 'foo')
    end
end
```

I get the UL & LI as expected.

I've tried swapping it around a bit doing:

```
def foo_list items
    contents = items.map {|item| content_tag(:li, item)}
    content_tag( :ul, contents )
end
```

In that case I get the whole list but the LI tags are html escaped (even though the strings are HTML safe). Doing `content_tag(:ul, contents.join("\n").html_safe )` works but it feels wrong to me and I feel `content_tag` should work in block mode with a collection somehow.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Try this:

```
def foo_list items
  content_tag :ul do
      items.collect {|item| concat(content_tag(:li, item))}
  end
end
```

Comment: That works, I'd tried doing the concat around the collect, previously rather than within. With concat inside the proc then collect isn't needed and you can use a items.each (or other iterators).

Comment: This way you are calling concat on each element. I think that it would be cheaper to do items.collect{}.join("").html_safe

Comment: Can you explain how concat is working here? I thought concat has to be called on another object?

Comment: @Tallboy `concat` is explained here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-concat. The method is being called on the view context (I think). You may be confusing it with `String#concat`

Comment: Thank you, I couldnt find that method before. That explains it

Answer (score 8):

I couldn't get that work any better.

If you were using [HAML](http://haml-lang.com/) already, you could write your helper like this:

```
def foo_list(items)
  haml_tag :ul do
    items.each do |item|
      haml_tag :li, item
    end
  end
end
```

Usage from view:

```
- foo_list(["item_one", link_to("item_two", "#"), ... ])
```

Output would be correctly intended.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`content_tag_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/RecordTagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag_for), which works with collections:

```
def foo_list(items)
  content_tag(:ul) { content_tag_for :li, items }
end
```

**Update:** In Rails 5 `content_tag_for` (and `div_for`) were moved into a separate gem. You have to install the [`record_tag_helper`](https://github.com/rails/record_tag_helper) gem in order to use them.

Comment: content_tag_for removed in Rails 5

Answer (score 4):

Along with answers above, this worked for me well:

```
(1..14).to_a.each do |age|
  concat content_tag :li, "#{link_to age, '#'}".html_safe
end
```

Comment: May need to change <%= to <% in the template when doing this.

Answer (score 2):

The big issue is that content_tag isn't doing anything smart when it receives arrays, you need to send it already processed content. I've found that a good way to do this is to fold/reduce your array to concat it all together.

For example, your first and third example can use the following instead of your items.map/collect line:

```
items.reduce(''.html_safe) { |x, item| x << content_tag(:li, item) }
```

For reference, here is the definition of concat that you're running into when you execute this code (from actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/tag_helper.rb).

```
def concat(value)
  if dirty? || value.html_safe?
    super(value)
  else
    super(ERB::Util.h(value))
  end
end
alias << concat
```