# content_tag inside each block within helper class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I want to created a view helper in rails that allows syntax like the following:

```
<%= some_fancy_list @items do |h| %>
  <%= h.rows :class => "whatever" |item| %>
    <td><= item.id %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I've built this up to the effect of (this is a simplified version)

```
def some_fancy_list(items, &block)
  h = InternalHelper.new(:items => items)
  content_tag(:table) { block.call(h) }
end

class InternalHelper
  include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper
  include ActionView::Context

  def initialize
    ...
  end

  def rows(options = {}, &block)
    content_tag(:tbody) do
      @items.each do |item|
        content_tag(:tr, options) do
          block.call(item) if block_given?
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that the HTML it outputs isn't exactly what I expect.

```
<table>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

The `<tr>`'s are completely missing and the block content of `<td>`'s isn't even within the `<tbody>` tag.

I found this question here on StackOverflow: [Loop & output content_tags within content_tag in helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669523/loop-output-content-tags-within-content-tag-in-helper) and tried using `concat` however I get the following error:

```
undefined method `concat'
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with the context being lost within the `.each` but I'm at a loss as to how to address it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seemed to lie in the fact that another class outside of the context of the originally invoking view helper was being used.  The solution involved removing the includes for Content and TextHelper, then making a proxy method on the class which linked back to the context the class was invoked from.

```
# self is passed into the helper class:
h = InternalHelper.new(self, :items => items)

# then the helper class makes a proxy back to that parent instance
class InternalHelper
  # removed these:
  # include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper
  # include ActionView::Context

  # added this:
  def content_tag(*args, &block)
    @parent.content_tag(*args, &block)
  end
end
```

This basically makes it so that `content_tag` is called from the same context as if it were within the view helper and it does it in such a way that it becomes invisible when implementing features on the `InternalHelper` class.

Comment: And all the rest of the code is the same as in your initial question? (I could learn something from this to)

Comment: I kept the `map` instead of `each` within the `row` function and (obviously) there is some constructor code which assigns `@parent`.  Otherwise, yeah it's pretty much the same.

Comment: Ok, I deleted my suggestion (tried to at least), I totally missed that if you use content_tag with a block it *is* using `concat(<text>, block.binding)` (and that block must be the block from the view, not from another "level") - at least in older Rails, so my suggestion was misleading.