# Rails content_tag for <ul> element

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, content-tag

How would I get the following html output with the content_tag helper?

```
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
  </ul>
```

This is what I have currently

```
  content_tag(:ul) do
    a=*(1..5)
    a.each do |step_number|
      content_tag(:li, class: "step") do
        puts step_number
      end
    end
  end
```

### Update - Answer

Thanks to Peter's [Loop & output content_tags within content_tag in helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669523/loop-output-content-tags-within-content-tag-in-helper) link below, I was missing `concat` on the `li` items

```
  content_tag :ul do
    items.collect do |step_number|
      concat(content_tag(:li, step_number, class: "step"))
    end
  end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loop & output content\_tags within content\_tag in helper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669523/loop-output-content-tags-within-content-tag-in-helper)

Comment: (I don't think the splat `*` does what you think it does.) What output do you currently have?

Comment: @Phlip he seems to just be to create an array for iterating, in which case the splat a) won't work and B) isn't necessary... OP: Try (1..5).each do ... ;)

Comment: How do you use this solution for a nested one

Answer (score 3):

I guess all you have to fix is

```
content_tag(:ul) do
  (1..5).to_a.map do
    content_tag(:li, step_number, class: "step)
  end.reduce(&:+)
end
```

That should do the job!

Comment: I changed the splat that I had to to Anton's `1.upto 5`, but this didn't work (I also added the closing `"` that you had dropped)

Comment: Replacing the upto with a map does the job. Because of the join this generates, you have to add reduce at the end

Comment: The `reduce(&:+)` should be just after the first `end`. Also, I usually prefer `.join('')` instead of `reduce`.

Answer (score 3):

it works for me.

```
content_tag(:ul, :class => 'a class') do
  (1..5).each do |item|
    concat content_tag(:li, item)
  end
end

<ul class="a class">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```