# Rails nested list with concat content_tag in Helper

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, helper, concatenation

I'm trying to create something similar to this: [Using helpers in rails 3 to output html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561250/using-helpers-in-rails-3-to-output-html)

Here's my helper:

```
def section_references_to_html (section)
     concat content_tag (:ol, :class => 'sources') do
        section.references.each do |reference|
          concat content_tag (:li,content_tag(:a, reference.text, :src => reference.url))
        end
      end
  end
```

But it's returning all sorts of syntax errors:

```
/~/app/helpers/application_helper.rb:21: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
     concat content_tag (:ol, :class => 'sources') do
                             ^
/~/app/helpers/application_helper.rb:21: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
     concat content_tag (:ol, :class => 'sources') do
                                                  ^
/~/app/helpers/application_helper.rb:22: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting keyword_end
        section.references.each do |reference|
                                  ^
/~/app/helpers/application_helper.rb:23: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
          concat content_tag (:li,content_tag(:a, referen...
                            ^
/~/app/helpers/application_helper.rb:23: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
...       concat content_tag (:li,content_tag(:a, reference.tex...
...                               ^
/~/app/helpers/application_helper.rb:23: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
```

---

What am I doing wrong here? Maybe using partial would be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that you have spaces between `content_tag` and `(`. Try this:

```
def section_references_to_html(section)
  content_tag(:ol, class: 'sources') do
    section.references.each do |reference|
      content_tag(:li, content_tag(:a, reference.text, href: reference.url))
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This works, thanks. I thought you had to parse hashes to content_tag?

Comment: It wasn't because of the hash notation. I fixed some spacing issues and just rewrote the code how I would. Happy to help.

Comment: oh I didn't know you could write it like that.

Comment: I does still need the spacing removed from in between the `content_tag` & the brackets - as well as `src` changed to `href` besides that works a treat. Thanks

Comment: I had the same problem and your example helped me but it didnt work untill I added "concat" before the content_tag with a "li" element