# How to integrate HTML with ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am new in ROR

I want integrate `html` code with `ROR Code` Like PHP

**This is php Exmple code:-**

```
$output='';

$output.='<div>how r you?</div>';
$output.='<div> fine</div>';

echo $output;
```

**Output**

```
how r you? fine
```

Help how to integrate html with ROR code? Like php see above the php code.

Answer (score 0):

Use [String#+](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-2B), it's like PHP's `.` String operator:

```
output = "Hello"
output += " world!" # same as output = output + " world!"
```

Or use [String#<<](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-3C-3C)

```
output = "Hello"
output << " world!"
```

Which is the same as [String#concat](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-concat):

```
output = "Hello"
output.concat(" world")
```

The last two examples modify the contents of `output`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use helpers to integrate html code with the ROR code.

In the helpers itself you can generate tags as `<p>` or  `<div>` and close them after inserting the data from the back end

In short you can generate html pages dynamically in the helpers. Helpers are particularly for views

You can refer to the below link for more clarity

[Using helpers in rails 3 to output html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561250/using-helpers-in-rails-3-to-output-html)

Answer (score 0):

In rails there is a available method called html_safe(). You can use this to integrate html code in .html.erb file

**controller:-**

`@test = ("<h1>Test case</h1>").html_safe`

**html.erb:-**

`<%= @test %>`

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to print html on page:

## Controller

```
@data = "<h1>Testing...</h1>"
@data=+ "<h2>Hello</h2>"
```

## view

```
<%= @data.html_safe %>
```

OR

```
<%= raw(@data) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Controller**

```
@data = "<h1>Testing...</h1>"
@data=+ "<h2>Hello</h2>"
```

**Views**

```
<%= @data.html_safe%>
```